# "Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range"

Tags: java

Here is the problem: Return true if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string.  Examples: catDog("catdog") → true; catDog("catcat") → false; catDog("1cat1cadodog") → true

```
  public boolean catDog(String str) {
  int countCat=0;
  int countDog=0;
  for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
  {
     if (str.charAt(i)== 'c'&& str.length()>=3)
       {
          if (str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat"))
          countCat++;
       }
  }
  for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
  {
     if (str.charAt(i)== 'd' && str.length()>=3)
       {
          if (str.substring(i,i+3).equals("dog"))
          countDog++;
       }
  }
  if (countCat == countDog)
      return true;
  else
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Please change your title to be more descriptive.

Comment: The code seems to be working for me. What's your problem, exactly?

Comment: It gives the error "Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range " when the input is (catxdogxdogxca)

Comment: Thanks for the edit of your title. 1+ Can you tell us which line throws this exception?

Comment: if (str.charAt(i)== 'c'&& str.length()>=3)
@Hovercraft

Comment: @EmanHamed Actually this code was reason of your problem, but code which was throwing exception was `str.substring(i, i + 3)`. It was throwing this exception because value of second argument for last two characters was greater then strings length so it was out of its bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loops conditions you are checking if entire String has length greater or equal `3` instead of checking only part from `i` till end. Try maybe with

```
str.length() - i >= 3
```

instead of

```
str.length() >= 3
```

Comment: Yes !! True.. I've just replaced str.length() >= 3 by str.length()- i >=3 and it was right ! Thank you

Comment: @EmanHamed You are welcome :) Next time when you post problem which is caused by error don't forget to include stacktrace (informations from error). Help us help you :)

Comment: Actually, it is my first time to use Stack overflow .. so I didn't know the rules but anyways. I will :D :D Thank u

Comment: @EmanHamed I it not rule, just common sense. The more relevant details you provide the more false causes of problem we would be able to eliminate or have to check, so we will be able to answer your question faster and with more precision. Anyway welcome on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

```
str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat")
```

`i` might be the last and `i+3` will give an error

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use [`StringUtils#countMatches`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

```
StringUtils.countMatches(myStr, "cat") == StringUtils.countMatches(myStr, "dog");
```

Don't get lost with the indexes. However, if you don't want to use this method, debugging your code is the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is what I might do:

The problem was with your check `str.length() >= 3`. It should have been `i + str.length()`.

I also suggest some changes to your code to get rid of duplication. Here I extracted the part that counts the number of appearances of a substring and moved it to its own method. The part that checks if count of cat equals count of dog now calls said method twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(catDog("catdog"));
    System.out.println(catDog("catcat"));
    System.out.println(catDog("1cat1cadodog"));
    System.out.println(catDog("catdogcatc"));//Would previously throw error.
}

public static boolean catDog(String str) {
    int countCat = countAppearances(str, "cat");
    int countDog = countAppearances(str, "dog");
    return countCat == countDog;
}

private static int countAppearances(String str, String key) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == key.charAt(0) && i + key.length() <= str.length()) {
            if (str.substring(i, i + key.length()).equals(key)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your first condition before spiting you string like:

```
if (str.charAt(i)== 'c' && (str.length() - i) >= 3)
{
    if (str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat"))
        countCat++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public boolean catDog(String str) {
     int catCount = 0, dogCount = 0;
//run a for loop to check cat count
//run loop till 2nd last character
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
//now check if the charaters at positions matches "cat"
//if matches then increment cat count
      if (str.charAt(i) == 'c' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 't') {
       catCount++;
      } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'd' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'o' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'g') {
//else check if the charaters at positions matches "dog"
//if matches then increment dog count
       dogCount++;
      }
     }

//check cat count and dog count
     if (catCount == dogCount) {
      return true;
     } else {
      return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.